# How to distinguish argument types (tuple/list of tuples) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have `getDict()` function that should accept tuple or list of tuples:

```
def getDict(items):
    item1,item2=items
    print item1,item2

getDict(({1:'a'},{2:'b'}))
getDict([({1:'a'},{2:'b'})])
```

But it gives me an error:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I know that it can be fixed with following snipped:

```
if type(items) == list:
    item1,item2=items[0]
else:
    item1,item2=items
```

But I'm seeking for a solution without if.

Comment: These inputs are not equivalent, first one is a sequence (tuple) of dictionaries, second one is a sequence (list) of sequence (tuple) of dictionaries. Therefore branch [if] is necessary.

Comment: Try this: `getDict([{1:'a'},{2:'b'}])`

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to achieve. Please note that the second getDict has one level of depth more than the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible ways to do it. You can check a type of your input: is it a tuple or a list. Or you can always use it a as list.

```
def get_dict_cast(tuple_or_list):
    """ This function casts it's args to list. """
    now_list = list(tuple_or_list)
    print(now_list, now_list.__class__) 

def get_dict_type_check(input):
    """ 
    This function checks what to do with your input depending on it's type.
    """
    if isinstance(input, tuple):
         print('it is a tuple: {}'.format(input))
    elif isinstance(input, list):
         print('it is a list: {}'.format(input))

just_tuple = ({ 1: 'a' }, { 2: 'b' })
list_of_tuples = [
    just_tuple, 
    ({ 3: 'a' }, { 2: 'b' })
]

get_dict_cast(just_tuple)
get_dict_cast(list_of_tuples)

get_dict_type_check(just_tuple)
get_dict_type_check(list_of_tuples)
```

The output will be:

```
# get_dict_cast(just_tuple):
[{1: 'a'}, {2: 'b'}], <type 'list'>

# get_dict_cast(list_of_tuples):
[({1: 'a'}, {2: 'b'}), ({3: 'a'}, {2: 'b'})], <type 'list'>

# get_dict_type_check functions:
it is a tuple: ({1: 'a'}, {2: 'b'})
it is a list: [({1: 'a'}, {2: 'b'}), ({3: 'a'}, {2: 'b'})]
```

Depending on what your are doing both methods might be usefull or useless.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you seeking is *multimethod*. I have found several implementations in PyPI, but used simple module written by Guido van Rossum: [Five-minute Multimethods in Python](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605)

They can be easily used like this:

```
@multimethod(tuple)
def getDict(items):
    item1,item2=items
    print item1,item2

@multimethod(list)
def getDict(items):
    return getDict(items[0])

getDict(({1:'a'},{2:'b'}))
getDict([({1:'a'},{2:'b'})])
```